# wait until the snapshot is completed with boto3 and lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, snapshot

i wrote python code in lambda to create snapshot and wait until it completed to execute the rest of the code but i have error
the error

```
"errorMessage": "Parameter validation failed:\nUnknown parameter in input: \"SnapshotsId\", must be one of: Filters, MaxResults, NextToken, OwnerIds, RestorableByUserIds, SnapshotIds, DryRun",
  "errorType": "ParamValidationError",
```

the code

```
from __future__ import print_function
import botocore
import boto3
import urllib.request

def lambda_handler(event, context):
        ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='eu-west-1')
        snapshot1 = ec2_client.create_snapshot(VolumeId='vol-054c95927bb8ed4a9', Description='Created by Lambda backup function ebs-snapshots')

       try:
            snapshot_id = snapshot1['SnapshotId']
            snapshot_complete_waiter = ec2_client.get_waiter('snapshot_completed')
            snapshot_complete_waiter.wait(SnapshotsId=['snapshot_id'])

        except botocore.exceptions.WaiterError as e:
            if "max attempts exceeded" in e.message:
                print("snapshot not completed")
            else:
                print(e.message)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use `SnapshotIds` instead of `SnapshotsId`:

```py
from __future__ import print_function
import botocore
import boto3
import urllib.request

def lambda_handler(event, context):
        ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='eu-west-1')
        snapshot1 = ec2_client.create_snapshot(VolumeId='vol-054c95927bb8ed4a9', Description='Created by Lambda backup function ebs-snapshots')

       try:
            snapshot_id = snapshot1['SnapshotId']
            snapshot_complete_waiter = ec2_client.get_waiter('snapshot_completed')
            snapshot_complete_waiter.wait(SnapshotIds=[snapshot_id])

        except botocore.exceptions.WaiterError as e:
                print(e)
```

Comment: i edit it but i have another error "errorMessage": "'WaiterError' object has no attribute 'message'",
  "errorType": "AttributeError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 44, in lambda_handler\n    if \"max attempts exceeded\" in e.message:\n"
  ]

Comment: Waiter will try every 15 sec to get Snapshot_completed for 40 times then it will throw an error msg. Here you can find more info: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Waiter.SnapshotCompleted

Comment: Change the part except with this and problem will be fixed: ```except botocore.exceptions.WaiterError as e:
                print(e.message)
       ```

Comment: Sorry, I have miss editted ```except botocore.exceptions.WaiterError as e: print(e)``` Now it will show the error message from AWS.

Comment: please can i ask you another question i try to remove the try and except then run the code 
 ```
 snapshot_id = snapshot1['SnapshotId']
        print(snapshot_id)
        snapshot_complete_waiter = ec2_client.get_waiter('snapshot_completed')
        snapshot_complete_waiter.wait(SnapshotIds=['snapshot_id'])       
          
   ``` 
i had that error "errorMessage": "Waiter SnapshotCompleted failed: Value (snapshot_id) for parameter snapshotId is invalid. Expected: 'snap-...'.",
  "errorType": "WaiterError",
  "stackTrace": [

Comment: It seems that your snapshotId is not correct. Consider to check it for typo mistakes and empty spaces. AWS expect a snapshotID such that 'snap-...' something like this.

Comment: i try to print(snapshot_id) i have that value (snap-0aec1a7a539f35e31)

Comment: Can you change this ```SnapshotIds=['snapshot_id']``` with ```SnapshotIds=[snapshot_id]```. You have given a string for SnapshotIds instead of AWS SnapshotID.

Answer (score -1):

Use this function:

```
snapshot.wait_until_completed()
```

ref: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Snapshot.wait_until_completed